# Spotlight can't find a jar file—why?

Tags: spotlight, java

Firefox.app and dimsum.jar are in the same directory.  If I double-click on either, the app launches and it works as expected.  Spotlight finds Firefox.app if I type "fire" but if I type "dim" or "dimsum," it only finds folders named "dimsum" containing related data files.  It finds "dimsum.jar" only if I type in the entire name.

Reason, and fix ?